# Where are these references coming from in this AWS SAM snippet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

In this documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-controlling-access-to-apis-cognito-user-pool.html

there's this snippet of SAM template:

```yaml
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors: "'*'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyCognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyCognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !GetAtt MyCognitoUserPool.Arn

  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        Root:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /
            Method: GET

  MyCognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Ref CognitoUserPoolName
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      Schema:
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: email
          Required: false
  
  MyCognitoUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      UserPoolId: !Ref MyCognitoUserPool
      ClientName: !Ref CognitoUserPoolClientName
      GenerateSecret: false
```

Where are `CognitoUserPoolName` and `CognitoUserPoolClientName` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is just a snippet from a CloudFormation template. `CognitoUserPoolName` and `CognitoUserPoolClientName` are strings which should be specified by you. One way of doing this is by passing them as parameters:

```yaml
Parameters:
  CognitoUserPoolName:
    Type: String
    Description: Cognito User Pool name
  CognitoUserPoolClientName:
    Type: String
    Description: Cognito User Pool Client name
```